# Update magento attribute field based on value from a 'custom' table

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, database-update

I use m2epro as an ebay module. I have a 3rd party erp. I want to pull the m2epro value down with the api. 
I figured the best way to do that way to tie the m2epro value into an product attribute and have the api call that value. I call attributes down all the time. I'm a little lost on what's the 'Magento' way to work with as an outside core table as I don't want to just run mysql update scripts or procedures to accomplish this. This is the update script I would use for this sample.

```
update catalog_product_entity_decimal t INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity a ON a.entity_id = t.entity_id INNER JOIN m2epro_ebay_listing_product b ON b.online_sku = a.sku SET t.value = b.online_buyitnow_price where t.attribute_id = 2862
```